# awk :: use case insensitive to find common words in 2 files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have two files called `1.txt` and `2.txt`.

In `1.txt` we can find these words:

```
apple
orange
butter
flower
```

In `2.txt` we can find these words:

```
dog
cat
Butter
tower
```

I can use the command

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} ($0 in a)' 1.txt 2.txt`

to find the common lines in the two files but the word `Butter` or `butter` is not returned because it has a capital letter in one of the two files.

How to return `butter` or `Butter`?

I just want to find the common lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easier with `grep`

```
$ grep -iwFf file1 file2
Butter
```

or with `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)]; next} tolower($0) in a' file1 file2
Butter
```

Comment: Ok for `awk` but strangely  `grep` is returning nothing https://snipboard.io/m0h6kX.jpg

Comment: I noticed that your `awk` code works only if there is 1 word per line. Is it possible to use `awk` to compare two files with words inline?

Comment: anythıng ıs possıble!, here awk script compares line against line regardless of how many words are there.  My guess is you're looking for any word match but the original post doesn't ask for this.  This may justify a new question with input and expected output to emphasize required "matching"

Comment: FYI: that's why `grep` was not working https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6518

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani that's Windows line ending issue.  If you create the files in Unix system it will have the right one.  Otherwise you need to `dos2unix` the files.